# How to get all User Input from a for loop in Django

Tags: python, django

Iam trying to display all the created departments in a form of HTML inputs and take user input (value1, vlaue2) and update department table with respect to "DepartmentID". the problem is it is taking only the first value from the loop how to get all the inputs from the for loop.

> template

[Department_template](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rpxKo.png)

```
 <input type="submit" value="Submit" >

{% for department in departments %}

<div class="row">
  <div class="col-sm-3">
  <label>value1</label>
    <input name="value1" class="form-control" />
  </div>
</div>

<br />

<div class="row">
  <div class="col-sm-3">
  <label>value2</label>
    <input name="value2" class="form-control" />
  </div>
</div>

{% endfor %}
```

> Views.py

```
def department(request):
departments = Department.objects.all()
value1 = request.POST.getlist('BUID')
value2 = request.POST.getlist('GBUID')
for department in departments:
    print(value1)
    print(value2)

context = {'departments': departments}
return render(request, 'employee/department.html', context)


------------------------------------------------------------------
Output:

['1']
['2']
['1']
['2']
------------------------------------------------------------------

------------------------------------------------------------------
What I want:

['1']
['2']      and update DepartmentID that equals to 123 with value1 = 1 value2 = 2

['3']
['4']     update DepartmentID that equals to 43534 with value1 = 3 value2 = 4
------------------------------------------------------------------
```

Comment: could you please show us your models.py for the Departement Class ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you need is a [model formset](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/topics/forms/modelforms/#model-formsets) which will generate a set of model forms, one for each instance in the queryset you specify. Based on the above the model is `Department` and the default queryset will be the one you want, `Department.objects.all()`

You should read the documentation for model forms and for formsets first, if you aren't familiar with these concepts.